# How to open a named mutex in kernel mode under Windows?

Tags: windows, kernel

Provided that we have two threads A and B; A is a user-mode thread, and B is a kernel-mode thread.

As we know, if A calls `CreateEvent` to create a named event, then B can open the named event in kernel mode.

However, if A calls `CreateMutex` to create a named mutex, how does B open the named mutex in kernel mode?

Why is there no `ZwOpenMutant` akin to `ZwOpenEvent` in kernel mode?

**Furthermore, what's the difference between a user-mode mutex and a kernel one?**

Comment: Reading between the lines of the documentation, it appears that kernel mutexes are completely different objects to user mutexes.  The kernel refers to user mutexes as mutants.  Kernel mutexes can only be used in kernel mode and must be released before a thread can transition back to user mode.

Answer (score -1):

**ZwOpenMutant** is not exported by Ntoskrnl.exe.

You can use [NtOpenMutant](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/UserMode/Undocumented%20Functions/NT%20Objects/Mutant/NtOpenMutant.html) counterpart function.

```
UNICODE_STRING Us;

NTSTATUS NtStatus;

OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES Oa;

HANDLE h = NULL;

RtlInitUnicodeString(&Us, L"COOL_MUTEX_HAHA");

InitializeObjectAttributes(&Oa,&Us,0,NULL,NULL);

Nttatus = NtCreateMutant(&h, MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS, &Oa, 0);

if(status == STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_COLLISION)
{
   NtStatus = NtOpenMutant(&h, MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS, &Oa);
}
```

Comment: Note that since the function is not documented in MSDN, it would be safer to use an alternative mechanism if at all possible.  For example, you can implement a simple mutex with an event, a single page of shared memory, and interlocked operations.

Comment: My answer points than ZwOpenMutant function exists, but is not exported. But yes, is safer use documented stuff.